# How many php scripts can my server run simultaneously?

Tags: php

I've a script accesible by the end user that makes the following call:

```
exec("php orderWatcher.php $insertedId > /dev/null &");
```

In orderWatcher.php I do some operations that take a long time:

```
 if (checkSomeStuff) {
     sleep(60);
 }
 makeOtherStuff();
```

I'm aware that I can have as many php scripts running as users requesting them, but I'm not sure if that remains true when I make an exec() call, since (according to my understanding) this executes a shell like command in the system.

Further more, if I perform the tests (This tests have been modified to keep them relevant to question, they have actually a lot more meaning than this):

```
class OrderPlacerResultOrders extends UnitTestCase {

    function testSimple() {
        exec("php orderWatcher.php $insertedId > /dev/null &");
        // Wait for exec to finish
        sleep(65);
        $this->assertTrue(orderWatcherWorked(1));
        // No problem here

     }

     function testComplex() {
        for($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
             exec("php orderWatcher.php $insertedId > /dev/null &");
        }
        // Wait a really long time
        sleep(1000);
        for($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
        $this->assertTrue(orderWatcherWorked(i));
        // Failure arround the 17th case
        }


     }

}
```

The tests aren't the main point, the test made me question the following:

1. How many exec calls to a php script can be made and handled by the server?
2. If there's a limited amount, it makes a diference that the exec is being requested by two instances of the script (As two different web users calling the script that makes the exec call)? Or is it the same as being called in the same script (As in the tests)?

PD: Coudln't think of any tags besides php, if you do think of one please tag the question

Comment: Although it depends on a lot of things, memory is probably the first problem you will run into; each request uses some and the amount you have is limited.

Comment: @jeroen But for example I don't worry about memory when the request are being made by the end user to a script. Why do I worry when the request is made via exec? Point 2 of my question is which worries me most

Comment: Is `sleep` actually part of your code, or is that just indicative of the time the real function takes?

Comment: @MatthewJohnson sleep is actual part of the code.

Comment: @jeroen Agreed. But I know (at least I think I know) that if a hundred users request a php script the server will suffice. But with a hundred calls to exec it doesn't

Comment: It's late, and I've had a few drinks, but I think there ought to be a beeter way to structure that.  `sleep` is going to keep a process running while no actual work is being done.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: I never actually finished writing my comment but accidentally posted it anyway... What I would personally do in your situation, is add all jobs to a job queue and have a task scheduler like cron check the queue periodically for any jobs to run. That allows you to make sure only one instance of your script runs. And I cannot imagine a situation where I would ever need `sleep()`. At least not in a script :-)

Comment: @jeroen I have a stock on which I need to check the value in x seconds from the moment the script is started. That's why I'm using sleep(x) before checking the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a command via exec or by a URL doesn't change the amount of scripts that can be run at the same time.
The amount of scripts that a server can run at the same time depend on it's memory alongside with a number of other factors.