# Run php script in exactly x seconds from now

Tags: php, performance, delay

I've a php script that posts orders on my database. Due to the nature of the order I must make  check in "x" seconds since the order was posted to an external site. This is all internal to the server and should not be interrupted if the user closes the connection

Currently I'm running the order posting script like this:

```
// Magical order posting
exec("php orderWatcher.php $insertedId > /dev/null &");
```

And orderWatcher.php :

```
 // Retrieve the value of x with the $insertedId param
 sleep("x");
 // Magical external checking
```

This works perfectly fine. But making a stress test of a hundred orders per second the server fails to handle them. In my other question about [maximum server scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840750/how-many-php-scripts-can-my-server-run-simultaneously) I was told that `sleep()` was clogging the server with dormant scripts.

I've thougth about making a thread that is constantly checking for orders in which "x" seconds have passed and perform the external checking but it seems that it would be clogging the database unnecessarily.

How can I tell the server: Execute the following script in "x" seconds from now, independently that the user has closed the connection ? (And not clogging the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a daemon to do this that runs all the time. You could model it on the `cron` idea:

- Read the list of jobs
- Work out when the next job is due
- sleep until then
- execute job
- rinse & repeat.

You'd need to add some logic to handle those periods where there are no outstanding jobs and a new job has to be added.

Your active tasks just need to leave a job in a queue somewhere - a database table will probably suffice - and your daemon handles the background processing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong.
You wan't to run this script regardless the user is connected or not i.e. You want the server to perform this task not the user.

For this task you may utilize **Corn Jobs**.

The **cronTab**, or "**Cron Table**", is a Linux system process / daemon which facilitates the scheduling of repetitive tasks thereby easing up our day to day routine.

So, for example, if one wanted to schedule a task for 12am on the first day of every month it would look something like this:

```
0 0 1 * * home/path/to/command/the_command.sh
```

For more information on corn jobs have a look at:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

I hope it helps.

Comment: The job isn't repetitive. The job is scheduled to run only once in "x" seconds from an action of the user. I had looked into cron jobs but it's not the solution